# On the history of Haar measure

Tags: mathematics, topology, group-theory

Haar measure is a well-known concept in measure theory.

Many books are perfectly dedicated to present its existence and uniqueness such as measure theory for D. Cohn.

I am looking for a good reference on the history of Haar measure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cohn himself](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-0399-0_9) recommends historical notes at the end of sections 15, 16 of [Abstract Harmonic Analysis by Hewitt and Ross, volume 1](https://books.google.com/books/about/Abstract_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=innmCAAAQBAJ). Here is an excerpt:

> "*Invariant integration on one or another special class of groups has
>   long been known and used. A detailed computation of the invariant
>   integral on $\mathfrak{SD}(n)$ was given in 1897 by HURWITZ [1]. SCHUR and
>   FROBEKius in the years 1900-1920 made frequent use of averages over finite groups; for references, see the notes in WEYL [3]. SCHUR in [ 1]
>   computed and applied intensively the invariant integrals for $\mathfrak{SD}(n)$
>   and $\mathfrak{D}(n)$. WEYL in [1] computed the invariant integrals for $\mathfrak{U}(n)$,
>   $\mathfrak{SD}(n)$, the unitary subgroup of the symplectic group, and [more or less
>   explicitly] for certain other compact Lie groups. WEYL and PETER in [1]
>   showed the existence of an invariant integral for any compact Lie group.*
>
> *The decisive step in founding modern harmonic analysis was taken by
>   A. HAAR [3] in 1933. He proved directly the existence [but not the
>   uniqueness] of left Haar measure on a locally compact group with a
>   countable open basis. His construction was reformulated in t erms of
>   linear functionals and extended to arbitrary locally compact groups by
>   A. WEIL [1], [2], and [4], pp. 33 -38. KAKUTANI [2] pointed out also
>   that HAAR's construction can be extended to all locally compact groups.
>   Theorem ( 15. S) as stated is thus due to WEIL. The proof we present
>   is due to H. CARTAN [1].*
>
> *For an arbitrary compact group G, VON NEUMANN [5] proved the
>   existence and uniqueness of the Haar integral, as well as its two-sided
>   and inversion invariance. In [6], VON NEUMANN proved the uniqueness
>   of left Haar measure for locally compact G with a countable open basis;
>   a special case was also established by Sz.-NAGY [1 ]. WEIL [ 4], pp. 37-38,
>   proved the uniqueness of the left Haar integral for all locally compact
>   groups.*"

Answer (score 5):

Try these references:

- Section 7.5 of *History of Topology*, edited by I. M. James.
- Section 2.2 of the chapter ["Topological Features of Topological Groups"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0470-0_5) in *Handbook of the History of General Topology*, volume 3, edited by C.E. All and R. Lowen